# Site-to-site VPN with multiple WAN links

Tags: openvpn, ipsec, site-to-site-vpn, l2tp, wide-area-network

I want to set up a site-to-site VPN using multiple ISPs and WAN links, such that all traffic to/from site A goes via site B, and the implementation details are completely transparent to the LAN at each end.

I've had a good look at the Peplink devices that have been widely recommended in response to similar questions, but site B will probably be a cloud-hosted environment. That makes a hardware solution less than ideal. I've also checked out a couple of service providers who offer link aggregation as a service, but for a fairly high price.

Can this be done with a combination of open protocols, to avoid sticker shock and vendor lock-in?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at MLPPP - Multi-Link PPP. Its capabilities should meet what you described with probably even non-appliance (a.k.a. pure software) implementations as well.

Comment: I've used MLPPP for multiple DSL lines, but I've yet to see an implementation of MLPPP that can take advantage of multiple WAN links that have different speeds (DSL, WiFi, 3G, etc).

Comment: It's commonly used to bond multiple DS1 circuits at the telco level and the implementations are not limited to bonding "like" circuits.